# NSFetchedResultsController didChangeObject indexPath is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using NSFetchedResultsController to manage an implementation of PSTCollectionView with CoreData. When I implement the following method the indexPath & newIndexPath parameters both come through as null

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
            NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
            NSLog(@"______");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I have been bashing my head against a brick wall with this for a few hours so would appreciate any pointers. Could it be something to do with multithreading? I am processing a large JSON file in a background thread on a separate NSManagedObjectContext instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because inserts don't have an [old]indexPath? Check the `newIndexPath` argument

Comment: I thought I was logging out newIndexPath. that typo has cost me 3 hours. Thanks for your help